I am using search box to search for books in my library management system app built using angular
On the navbar I have a search box for searching books in the app, I am using search button for it so as to show results only when search is clicked. But after the search you have to manually clear the Text Field and search again to display all results. How can I fix this?
I tried using angular service and passed the search string and filtered the result to show on the page. I was expecting when I clear Text field the results will dynamically update and the user can use search button and Text Field for searching.


//variable for the search service (a signal so the user knows when the status changes)
searchStatus = signal(''");
I am getting the changed search Text using signal and using it for search.
